# How does the quotechar parameter of the csv reader function work?

Tags: python, csv

My current understanding of the quotechar parameter is that it surrounds the fields that are separated by a comma. I'm reading the csv documentation for python and have written a similar code to theirs as such:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv", newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

My csv file contains the following:

```
|Hello|,|My|,|name|,|is|,|John|
```

The output gives a list of strings as expected:

```
['Hello', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'John']
```

The problem arises when I have whitespace in between the commas in my csv file.
For example, if i have a whitespace after the closing | of a field like such:

```
|Hello| ,|My| ,|name| ,|is| ,|John|
```

It gives the same output as before but now there's a whitespace included in the strings in the list:

```
['Hello ', 'My ', 'name ', 'is ', 'John']
```

It was my understanding that the quotechar parameter would only consider what was between the | symbol.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would advise not to place spaces outside the quotes - different parsers may produce different results.. If a space is needed either put it inside the quotes, or use no quotes at all for that field. Spaces around the field 'should' be included in the field, but parsers start to behave differently once quotes are present and the space is outside of the quotes (some might even raise a parsing error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The `quotechar` argument is

> A one-character string used to quote fields containing special
> characters, such as the delimiter or quotechar, or which contain
> new-line characters. It defaults to '"'.

**For example,**

If your `csv` file contains data of the form

```
|Hello|,|My|,|name|,|is|,|"John"|
|Hello|,|My|,|name|,|is|,|"Tom"|
```

then in that case you can't use the default `quotechar` which is `"` because its already present in entities of the csv data so to instruct the csv reader that you want `"John"` to be included as it is in the output you would specify the some other `quotechar`, it may be `|` or `;` or any character depending on the requirements.

The output now include `John` and `Tom` in quotation marks,

```
['Hello', 'My', 'name', 'is', '"John"']
['Hello', 'My', 'name', 'is', '"Tom"']
```

**Consider another example** where csv field itself contains `delimiter`, consider the `csv` file contains

```
"Fruit","Quantity","Cost"
"Strawberry","1000","$2,200"
"Apple","500","$1,100"
```

Now in such case you have to specify the `quotechar` explicitly to instruct the csv reader so that it can distinguish between actual delimiter (control character) and comma (literal characters) in the csv field. Now in this case the `quotechar` `"` will also work.

---

Now coming to your code, you have to replace the extra white space before the `delimiter` in the `csv` file with the empty string. You can do this in the following way:

**Try this:**

```
from io import StringIO

with open("test.csv", newline="") as f:
    file = StringIO(f.read().replace(" ,", ","))
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

**This outputs,**

```
['Hello', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'John']
```

Comment: Yeah that would work but I'm trying to understand exactly what this quotechar parameter does and how it works.

Comment: @KrabbyPatty Hope  this helps you clear your understanding.