# pandas.read_csv() with delimiter and quotechar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, delimiter

#### Issue

I have a pipe-delimited data set where *some* of the values also have pipes in them. These elements are enclosed by `\\` on either side to denote that pipes in between them should not be used as delimiters. The raw data looks like:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
1|some text|more text
2|some text|more text
3|\\text with a | in it\\|more text
4|\\a|b|c\\|more text
```

I want to read these into a pandas dataframe so that it looks like:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some text | more text |
| 2 | some text | more text |
| 3 | text with a | in it | more text |
| 4 | a|b|c | more text |

#### Attempt 1

If I just use

```py
pd.read_csv(path, sep='|')
```

I get the error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
...
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4
```

becuase the engine interprets row 3 as having 4 columns.

#### Attempt 2

I thought this would be solved using the `quotechar` parameter ([reference to docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))

```py
pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', quotechar='\\')
```

but this will leave the values as NaN rather than correctly parsed

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some text | more text |
| 2 | some text | more text |
| 3 | NaN | more text |
| 4 | NaN | more text |

#### Attempt 3

I tried using the `comment` parameter (though I don't think this is its intended use and got the same result as Attempt 2.

```py
pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', comment='\\')
```

Comment: the comment character comments out *until the end of the line* (unlike the C style `/* this is a comment */`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "quotechar" parameter is limited to **one** character. In your case you have two.

What you could do is preprocessing the file content to replace `\\` by another character, for example the canonical double quote `"`

```
import io

path = 'test.csv'

with open(path) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(f.read().replace(r'\\', '"')), sep='|')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  Col1       Col2  Col3
1            some text  more text   NaN
2            some text  more text   NaN
3  text with a | in it  more text   NaN
4                a|b|c  more text   NaN
```

*NB. You have an extra `|` at the end of each row except for the header, is this expected?*

Comment: Th extra `|` was accidental, I have edited the post. Also, this solution worked, but I needed to use `.replace('\\', '"') without the raw specifier.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `quotechar='\\'` doesn't work for you is because `quotechar` assumes any argument longer than one character is a regular expression.

I would try replacing that double backslash with a single backslash. Try something like this maybe:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

doubleslash = r"\\"

with open("test.csv", newline="") as f:
    file = StringIO(f.read().replace(doubleslash, "\\"))
    frame = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="|", quotechar="\\")

print(frame)
```

Note that we have to define the double backslash as a raw string, and that we are escaping the backslash in the quotechar and replacement char fields.

You can see a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902745/18375093