# Quotechar in Python

Tags: python

Please, help me undestand how 'quotechar' works with examples.

Can you please help me with quotechar, it's really tight. How does it work?  Here, for example, a csv file contains the string "Hello", "My", "name", "is", "John". quotechar='''', the program will output

[''Hello'', '''My''', '''name''', '''is''', '''John'''], and if you specify any other character in the quotechar, the program will output

[''''Hello''', '''''My''', '''''name''', '''''is''', '''''John'''], why this is so I can't understand.

If the csv file contains the string |Hello|,|My|,|name|,|is|,|John|, quotechar='|', the program will output

['Hello', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'John'],

but if you don't specify quotechar='|' in this case, the program will output

['|Hello|', '|My|', '|name|', '|is|', '|John|'].

Or if, for example, the string is 'Hello, my name', is, John, quotechar=''' the output would be

[''Hello, ''my name''', ''is'', ''John'']. Here, what is in double quotes is still separated by single quotes.

When should this qoutechar be used? And how to use it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the quotechar parameter of the csv reader function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60902650/how-does-the-quotechar-parameter-of-the-csv-reader-function-work)

Comment: Please, post [mre], incl. sample text/file